# How to move the selection to be after the just-pasted image in Word VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I wrote a macro which copy-pastes a chart in Excel into an open Word document.

Problems occur when users run the macro twice.  On the second round, the just-pasted image is still selected, so the new paste undoes the work of the previous by pasting over the current selection.

Near the end of the macro, **how do I unselect my just-pasted image** so the next macro run will work correctly and paste to its right?

My sample code:

```
Private Sub ActiveChartPasteToWordMacro(ByVal AndShrinkItToo)
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordCurrentPlace As Word.Range

    ' Copy the range as a picture
    Call ActiveChart.CopyPicture(Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap)

    ' Refer to the current place in the open Word document:
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    Set WordCurrentPlace = WordApp.Selection.Range

    ' Paste the Excel chart into Word
    Call WordCurrentPlace.Paste

    ' The user usually calls the macro with some rescaling factor, to fit three charts in a row in Word:
    If AndShrinkItToo Then
         Call WordApp.Selection.Expand(wdParagraph)
         WordApp.Selection.InlineShapes(WordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.count).ScaleWidth = 67
         WordApp.Selection.InlineShapes(WordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.count).ScaleHeight = 67
    End If

    ' ???? HOW DO I NOW SELECT THE SPACE AFTER THE IMAGE FOR THE NEXT RUN OF THE MACRO ????

    ' Clean up
    Set WordCurrentPlace = Nothing
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: do not use "Select" to place your picture

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think I found it.  The answer is to add the line `WordApp.Selection.Move`

Answer (score -1):

here is code for pasting side by side

correct the path to your picture and then single-step the code using F8 key

```
Sub pastePictures()

    Dim aaa As Object
    Dim bbb As Range

    Dim pic As String
    pic = "C:\myPicture.png"           ' put your picture's path here


    Set aaa = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture( _
        FileName:=pic, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True)

'    aaa.ScaleHeight = 10
'    aaa.ScaleWidth = 10

    Set bbb = aaa.Range
    bbb.Select                         ' for debug only

    bbb.Collapse wdCollapseEnd         ' this collapses the range taken up by the picture to zero
    bbb.Select                         ' for debug only

    Set aaa = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture( _
        FileName:=pic, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True)

'    aaa.ScaleHeight = 10
'    aaa.ScaleWidth = 10


End Sub
```